# Fetch API's json is printing undefined?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Trying to fetch from the API in JS and my returned JSON is returning undefined? And yes, it is valid JSON, although console.loging the data shows me undefined?

```
function getVideos(playlistId) {
    console.log(
        getJsonResponse(composeArguments(API_RESOURCE, API_KEY, playlistId))
    );
}


function composeArguments(apiResource, apiKey, playlistId, maxResults = 50) {
    return (
        apiResource +
        "?key=" +
        apiKey +
        "&part=snippet&playlistId=" +
        playlistId +
        "&maxResults=" +
        maxResults);
}

function getJsonResponse(url) {
    fetch(url).then((response) => {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
            console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + response.status);
            return;
        }

        response.json().then((data) => {
            return data;
        });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
    });

}




getVideos(PLAYLIST_ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

The function under fetch's *then* doesn't actually have a return value. So `console.log(getJsonResponse...` logs undefined. `getJsonResponse` must return something (either a promise or a value).

Instead of `response.json().then(data => { return data; })`, simply `return response.json();`

Comment: I've created a js fiddle, hopefully you can help further with this. Your suggestion didn't seem to work, thanks. https://jsfiddle.net/geym5fkp/

Answer (score 0):

try Appending return before response.json(). Rest seems fine. Called function should return some value.

```
`function getJsonResponse(url) {
   return fetch(url).then((response) => {
     if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + response.status);
        return 'Looks like there was a problem.';
    }

    return response.json().then((data) => {
        return data;
    });
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
});
```

}`

Comment: I've created a js fiddle, hopefully you can help further with this. Your suggestion didn't seem to work, thanks. https://jsfiddle.net/geym5fkp/